# Hive: aggregate function on array column

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive, aggregate-functions

I was wondering whether is possible to run an aggregate function over a column that has as data type array.

The table is created as per following:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tmp_table (
  start_date array<string>,
  customer_id string
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
  LOCATION '<my-s3-bucket>'
```

start_date contains a collection of dates comma separated. 
I want to find the minimum of those dates using the MIN function:

```
SELECT customer_id, MIN(start_date) FROM tmp_table GROUP BY customer_id
```

If MIN is not applicable to an array structure, what would be an alternative solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to sort array and take first element:

```
select customer_id, sort_array(start_date)[0] as min_start_date
  from tmp_table;
```

if table can contain more than one record for customer_id then take `min(sort_array(start_date)[0])`